# Передача дополнительной информации о событии в команду

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

При обработке события MouseDown в обработчик приходит `object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e` . Но так как событие я обрабатываю через команду, то мне нужно как-то этот `e` передать в нее. Как это сделать?

```
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=Step}">
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно подключить сборку `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions`.

```
    xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
               <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
                     <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="UIElement_OnMouseDown" 
                                          TargetObject="{Binding}" />
               </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

И в ViewModel создать метод:

```
public void UIElement_OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

В данном примере аргументы события передаются не в команду, а в метод.